# Appending object to list

Tags: python

I am trying to append objects to a list. However after the second append the first item change in the list.
Can you tell me how to make it work?

It works if `x` is not a `numpy` array but a simple float variable.

```py
import numpy as np

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, x_in):
        self.x = x_in

x = np.zeros((2, 1))
filters = []

x[0] = 1
filters.append(TestClass(x))
print(filters[0].x)

x[0] = 2
filters.append(TestClass(x))
print(filters[0].x)
print(filters[1].x)
```

Expected output:

```
[[1.]
 [0.]]

[[1.]
 [0.]]
[[2.]
 [0.]]
```

Actual output (first item changed):

```
[[1.]
 [0.]]

[[2.]
 [0.]]
[[2.]
 [0.]]
```

Comment: TestClass simply holds a reference to x. When you modify x, all references, including those in the instances of TestClass appended to the array, refer to the modified value. You don't even need TestClass. Just do `filters.append(np.reshape([1, 0], (2, 1)))`.

Comment: Thanks! The TestClass is just an example. In the real app I need to append classes. So the solution is: TestClass (copy.deepcopy(x))

Answer (score 0):

Solution (or at least it works):

filters.append(TestClass(copy.deepcopy(x)))

(I want to bang my head against the wall...)

EDIT (better performance - thx hpaulj):

filters.append(TestClass(copy.copy(x)))

Comment: Since `x` is a numpy array, you don't need `deepcopy`.  `x.copy()` is enough.  Your original problem arose because you mutated (changed) `x` between `appends`.  The list has multiple references to the same array object.